# How to pass a list of dictionaries as input to a Pydantic Langchain tool function :Langchain Schema Validation Error

Tags: python, openai-api, pydantic, langchain

Hi I am trying to create an agent tool that takes in structured input data as a list of dictionary and do summation on the 'price' key.

```
input_data=[{'Junk_Food_name': 'Meat Lovers Pizza', 'price': 800},
 {'Junk_Food_name': 'Chicken Alfredo Pizza', 'price': 800},
 {'Junk_Food_name': 'Cheeseburger Pizza', 'price': 800},
 {'Junk_Food_name': 'Chicken Bacon Ranch Pizza', 'price': 800},
 {'Junk_Food_name': 'Chicken Pesto Pizza', 'price': 800}]
```

Now I trying to pass the above input to the function I defined below as follow

```
from typing import List, Dict
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from langchain.agents import tool


# Define the input schema
class InputData(BaseModel):
    input_data: List[Dict[str, int]] = Field(description="List of input data with 'Junk_Food_name' and 'price' fields")

# Define the tool function
@tool(args_schema=InputData)
def calc_price(input_data:List[Dict[str, int]])-> int:
    """ Calculate the final price of the order placed"""
    sum_total = 0
    for item in input_data:
        sum_total += int(item['price'])
    
    return sum_total
```

But when I try to call the input on the above function I get the following error:-

```
ValidationError: 1 validation error for InputData
input_data
  field required (type=value_error.missing)
```

Can someone help to resolve the above error !!

I am expecting output to be 4000

Answer (score 1):

run:

```
pip show pydantic
```

you probably are using pydantic v2. langchain is still using langchain v1 BaseModel. so instead of this

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
```

use

```
from pydantic.v1 import BaseModel, Field
```

Comment: Just checked my pyndetic version and it is Name: pydantic
Version: 1.10.11

Comment: Thanks @Yilmaz, didn't notice they are still using v1.

Answer (score 0):

In your tool function you can pass an argument

```
handle_validation_error = True
```

then it will pass the input error as an observation to the langchain and the response will be generated according to that.

In your code it will be like

```
# Define the tool function
@tool(args_schema=InputData, handle_validation_error = True)
def calc_price(input_data:List[Dict[str, int]])-> int:
```

You can refer the code here

https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/master/libs/core/langchain_core/tools.py#L180C5-L180C28